# Relacionamento Laravel em Datatable server side

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, laravel-eloquent, datatable

Teria alguma maneira de passar o relacionamento da model para as colunas do Datatable server side?

Por exemplo no script do Datatable:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'marca_id', name: 'marca_id' },
    { data: 'automovel_modelo', name: 'automovel_modelo' },
    { data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
],
```

Onde o marca_id teria que receber o valor do relacionamento para exibir o nome da marca de acordo com o ID.

Função no model com relacionamento:

```
public function marca(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Config\Transito\AutomovelMarca');
}
```

Controller que exibe os dados:

```
public function getData ()
{
    $automovel_modelo = AutomovelModelo::all();

    return Datatables::of($automovel_modelo)
    ->addColumn('action', function($automovel_modelo){
        return 
            '<a href="automoveis_modelos/'. $automovel_modelo->id .'/edit" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" title="Editar">
               <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>' .
            '<a onclick="deleteData('. $automovel_modelo->id .')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';
    })
    ->make(true);


    return datatables(AutomovelModelo::query())->toJson();

}
```

Porém não descobri como passar o relacionamento para o json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer passar os valores da `marca` de cada `AutomovelModelo` para o `Datatable`, só que você não está carregando essa informações. Para isso, use a função `with` para carregar o relacionamento com `marca`, assim:

```
$automovel_modelo = AutomovelModelo::with('marca')->get();
```

Dessa forma, você irá carregar todas as informações da `marca` para cada `AutomovelModelo`.

Quanto a exibir no seu `Datatable` eu não saberia te dizer como fazer, mas, acho que se essa linha `{ data: 'automovel_modelo', name: 'automovel_modelo' },` exibir as informações de cada coluna do `AutomovelModelo`, você teria que substituir o `marca_id` por apenas `marca` nas colunas do seu `script` do `Datatable`.

Referências:

- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Ajudou bastante, na verdade tive que passar o argumento { data: 'marca.automovel_marca', name: 'marca.automovel_marca' }